# Exists in ESENT

Tags: c#, extensible-storage-engine

I'm trying to find out if a record exists in a table. 
Now, one obvious way would be to just seek for the record:

```
// Create correct keys for index with Api.MakeKey
Api.JetSeek(sessionId, tableId, SeekGrbit.SeekEQ);
```

However, this operation will set the cursor to the found record (on success), which I don't want to do.
I guess I could somehow just quikly store the current record number and then set it back, but maybe there is a better solution? I couldn't find the correct method in the api.

So, is it possible to do a Exists, meaning a Seek just to check if the record exists?

By the way, I'm using .NET 4.0 with the ESENT Managed Interface 1.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, get current position of cursor using [JetGetRecordPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.isam.esent.interop.api.jetgetrecordposition%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx) method

```
public static void JetGetRecordPosition(
    JET_SESID sesid,
    JET_TABLEID tableid,
    out JET_RECPOS recpos
)
```

Then check if record exist as you done

```
Api.JetSeek(sessionId, tableId, SeekGrbit.SeekEQ);
```

or using boolean method [TrySeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.isam.esent.interop.api.tryseek%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx) which returns true if a record matching the criteria was found.

```
public static bool TrySeek(
    JET_SESID sesid,
    JET_TABLEID tableid,
    SeekGrbit grbit
)
```

Then you need to set cursor on previous position, for doing it use [Api.JetGotoPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.isam.esent.interop.api.jetgotoposition%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx) method with recpos you got from first method.

```
public static void JetGotoPosition(
    JET_SESID sesid,
    JET_TABLEID tableid,
    JET_RECPOS recpos
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think I understand your answer correctly. So, I can get the IndexInfo of the currently applied index. How does that help me with checking if a record exists?

Comment: @Daniel, I completely changed my answer.

Comment: Ok, well, I guess if this is the only option (I already had outlined this in my question). In any case, thanks for the detailed description of how to work with the internal record positions, saves me some time finding out myself. I'll wait another day before awarding the bounty,just to make sure nobody has an even better idea

Answer (score 0):

Another technique is to use the `JetDupCursor()` method to create a new `JET_TABLEID` that is independent of the current `JET_TABLEID`.  That way the `TrySeek()` method will not alter the original cursor's position if the row is found

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.isam.esent.interop.api.jetdupcursor%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396